# How to change the grad scale values with tkzKiviatDiagram to non numeric values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-kiviat

Is there any way I can change the grad scale values generated with the help of *\tkzKiviatGrad* to non numeric values like `normal, flavorful and intense` instead of `1,2,3`. I'd checked out the [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-kiviat/doc/TKZdoc-kiviat-main.pdf) but couldn't find anything useful.

This is my current code snippet:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style={gray!50}, scale=1, gap=1, lattice=3]{pineapple,mango,durian}
    \tkzKiviatLine[thick,
                           color      = orange,
                           ball color = orange,
                           mark size  = 4pt,
                           fill       = orange!20](1,2,3)
\tkzKiviatGrad[](3)  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I compile it then it looks like the following:
[image]

What I try to achive is something like this:
[image]

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already a `tikzpicture`, you could keep the diagram and just add the labels.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style={gray!50}, scale=1, gap=1, 
lattice=3]{pineapple,mango,durian}
    \tkzKiviatLine[thick,mark=ball,
                           color      = orange,
                           ball color = orange,
                           mark size  = 4pt,
                           fill       = orange!20](1,2,3)
%\tkzKiviatGrad[](3)  
\foreach \X [count=\Y]in {normal, flavorful, intense}
\node[anchor=north,rotate=-30] at (\Y,0) {\X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Creative :) Why I did not think of this :)

Comment: @JouleV Must be related to our hibernation habits. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Exactly what I needed!
@JouleV Also thanks for your assistance and pointing in the right direction.
You've both been a great help!

Answer (score 2):

`tkz-kiviat` is based on Ti*k*Z, so let's use the more powerful and customizable Ti*k*Z! Well, it is not complicated at all...

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=orange!20,draw=orange,thick] (1,0) -- (120:2) -- (-120:3) -- cycle;
\draw[help lines] (0,0) -- (3.5,0) node[right,black] {pineapple};
\draw[help lines] (0,0) -- (120:3.5) node[above left,black] {mango};
\draw[help lines] (0,0) -- (-120:3.5) node[below left,black] {durian};
\draw[help lines] foreach \i in {1,2,3} {(\i,0) -- (120:\i) -- (-120:\i) -- cycle};
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {normal,flavorful,intense} 
    \path (\j,0) node[below,font=\tiny\sffamily] {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your swift and promising response! My original intention for using `tkz-kiviat` is that in a more complex scenario I'll be loading the _fruits_ and their values from a .dat file. Is there any way I could reuse your foreach loop to sort of override the labels?

Comment: @lxndrblz What do you mean by "sorting" the labels?

Comment: @lxndrblz If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: @JouleV I didn't mean sorting in the sense of arranging the items, but "sort of overriding" like replacing them. Does that make sense? Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @lxndrblz Yes. You only have to substitute `{normal,flavorful,intense}` with a list surrounded by braces, separated by commas, e.g. `{lxndrblz,abc,def,ghi}`. That's all. I don't think I will ever need anything other than Ti*k*Z to draw such figures.

Comment: @JouleV I'd like to accept your answer, but what remains unclear to me is if there is a way I could combine the TikZ! power for configuring the label nodes (like you've shown) with ability of tkz-kiviat to load the values (fruits) from a file. Is there such?

Maybe I need to clarify a bit more why I've chosen the setup with tkz-kiviat instead of directly using TikZ!. I have a separate section where I generate tables with additional information from the same .dat file as the one that I use for the Kiviat diagram. To keep table and diagram in sync I am changing the values in my .dat file.